# jquery wont pick the dynamically populated dropdown select box values

Tags: php, jquery, loops, if-statement, echo

i have an issue with jquery and php my problem is this:

i have used jquery .post method to send data to an external php page which then returns data from the page successfully however i load these values (which are options with option tags) into select elements which i then want to use those values in another .post request that sends them to the same external php page that deals with it differently in an if statement that determines if it is set however the main issue i ave is

why does it jump to the else and display an echo message from the php page

e.g.. 
dynamically sent options in php page

```
  while($fetch = mysql_fetch_array($sel2))
  {                 
  $options = "<option value=".$fetch['amount'].">" . $fetch['amount'] . "</option>";
  echo $options;
  }
```

i have 2 drop downs populated by external database with values in them and options however it doesnt pick the values up on the external php page

```
 if(isset($_POST['c']))
 {
$c = $_POST['c'];
discounts($c);
 }
 else
 {
$msg = "nothing entered!!";
$msg2 = 1;
$array = array($msg,$msg2);
$sent = implode(",",$array);
echo $sent; 
 }
```

can anyone tell me why it doesnt pick the value up?

Comment: well probably your $_POST['c'] isn't there on the second request. Inspect the form and make sure you have $_POST['c'] before you send it

Answer (score 0):

id do it like this in html?

```
<select id="options" name="optionsselect">
  <?php foreach($fetch as $whatever) : ?>
     <option value="<?=$whatever['amount'];?>"<?=$selected?>><?=$whatever['amount'];?></option>
  <?php endforeach; ?></select>
```

Comment: the while loop is in an external php page

Comment: print_r($_POST)? what is discounts?

Comment: a function being called to send a message to the browser in a span

Comment: o i see. why not why testing the post is there...print_r($_POST) and if so try changing if(isset($_POST['c']) to if(is_array($_POST)) or better yet if($_POST['c']!='')